# Java: Transfer a file from server to client and from client to server

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

I am a newbie and I want to accomplish file transfer from server to client "do something with it" and then send the file back to the server. The most basic code I am using is here:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(123456);
    File myFile = new File("s.pdf");
    while (true) {
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
      bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      sock.close();
    }
  }
}

The client module

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 123456);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("s.pdf");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

Got it from this website: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/TransferafileviaSocket.htm

I understand how this works but I don't know how to send a file back to the server. 
Please help.

Comment: sockets are bi-directional.  keep it open and read the response back from the server.

Comment: I would recommend you use HTTP and your "server" is a simple servlet. Then you just read the request and answer the response, the servlet API does the rest for you (and on the client the HTTPURLConnection or other HTTPClient code).

Comment: @jtahlborn so do I omit the sock.close() on server and client and then add reverse chains which write and read the data?

Comment: @eckes thank you for the recommendation, but do you think it would be possible to solve this without using HTTP?

Comment: @meowtwo sure it is. on the server just open is = socket.getInputStream() and os = socket.getOutputStream(). Read from one, write to the other. IT is just that there is a lot of additional things you need in production to make it reliable.

Comment: @eckes May I be so bold and ask you to provide an example in the given code?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a file transfer class in the past, you can use it both in your client and server (by making an instance) and use the methods to send and receive files as much as you want.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileTransferProcessor {
    Socket socket;
    InputStream is;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    int bufferSize;


    FileTransferProcessor(Socket client) {
        socket = client;
        is = null;
        fos = null;
        bos = null;
        bufferSize = 0;

    }

    void receiveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            is = socket.getInputStream();
            bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
            System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
            bos.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void sendFile(File file) {

        FileInputStream fis;
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        BufferedOutputStream out;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            int count;
            while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);

            }
            out.close();
            fis.close();
            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poor quality in several respects. The buffer doesn't need to be the size of the file, or anywhere near it: this doesn't scale to large files. 8192 bytes is sufficient for most purposes. `flush()` before `close()` is redundant, as is `socket.close()` after closing either its input or output streams. `IOExceptions` should never be just turned into booleans: they should be logged. Resources should be closed in `finally` blocks. The pattern of `try/catch` and then more code is poor practice. Code that relies on the success of code in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block.

Comment: I agree, thank you. I wrote this a while back and remember it worked for the most part so I did not bother to look too deeply into it. I will refine it with your recommendations as soon as I have the time.